# memcache or localStorage? Which is better to use?

Tags: html, memcached, local-storage

What is the difference, pros & cons...which is better to use?

Since I am developing since scratch, can put some light to create better application.

Comment: Your question is too vague. You're comparing apples to oranges, memcache and localStorage are not direct alternatives to each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LocalStorage is better if you need the data on the client.

memcached is better if you need the data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @Rik but in one of my AngulaJs application i have used local storage instead of memcached.

It will be slower when user first time fetching the record but from second time onward it will fetch from local storage instead of from server.